# Need help in choosing parts for a pcb

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, components, pcb-fabrication, component-selection

I am trying to get a PCB fabricated and assembled from PCBWay for a project, but I have little experience with electronic components. The project schematics don't have specifications for some of the parts, and I need some help in choosing the correct parts. The project information can be found here:

https://hackaday.io/project/165060-bluecubemod-bluetooth-gamecube-controller-mod-kit

The pcb design files (gerber, drill, eagle) can be seen here: https://github.com/NathanReeves/BlueCubeMod

The parts that I need help choosing are:

- U7 (NCP161 3V3 LDO voltage regulator): There are numerous parts whose with NCP161 as the prefix.
- U$4, U$5 (Diode): There are no specifications on diode parameters. Is this normal?
- L1 (EMIFIL (R) Chip Ferrite Bead for GHz Noise): There are numerous different kinds as part of this series.
- +, -, DATA, GRND: I believe these are connecting points for soldering wires to the PCB, but I'm not sure how that works when ordering the PCB. The schm files lists it as a part, but should it be included in the BOM? If so, what part would I use?

Appreciate any help in figuring these out.

Comment: Where is the schematic?

Comment: You can see a PDF of the schematics here: https://github.com/NathanReeves/BlueCubeMod/blob/master/PCB/BlueCubeModRev2Schematics.pdf

There's also a .sch file as well: https://github.com/NathanReeves/BlueCubeMod/blob/master/PCB/Eagle/BlueCubeModR2.sch

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not enough design information to help with part selections.  The '161 regulator is spec'd for 450 mA max.  Is this what's needed?  The two diodes are steering diodes for providing power from two sources.  Do they have to be able to carry 10 mA, 100 mA, 450 mA?

Comment: And no, I did not look at all 76 variations of the '161 regulator on the vendor's web page to try and figure out what you need.

Comment: Are you attempting to build this *not* from a kit?  It uses an ESP32-Pico-D4 - how are you going to program that?  It has to be programmed to do anything.

Comment: You'd probably get more helpful answers if you put pictures of the board and schematic with the uncertain components labeled. Otherwise it's hard to guess what you're asking about.

Comment: I didn't even think about flashing the ESP32-Pico-D4. I guess this won't really be possible without a lot more effort. I'm going to give up on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with NCP161, if you go at page 17 of the datasheet, you can find the difference between all models. With the Gerber's, you can figure out which package you need. Then, you know the voltage is 3.3V. The active discharge pin is a bit harder to know if you need the option or not. The only way to be sure, is by viewing the schematic, but chances are that they aren't even using it. (after seeing the schematic, he doesn't uses it)

For the diodes, you need to see the schematic, otherwise, anything can do it or not. After reviewing the schematic, the forward voltage of the diode shouldn't be much of an issue. Just take anything that fit in the footprint and can feed at least around 450mA and you should be fine. A lower forward voltage will help with the battery, so I would probably look in Schottky diodes.

For L1, many designers uses liberally ferrites. Most design don't need any. In that instance, it might be preferable to place one but I doubt it. I would place a 0ohm resistor in there. But otherwise, if you want to place a ferrite, place one that can handle 450mA and you should be fine. You are not doing production or compliance with that thing, so it's extremely unlikely that it will change anything.

Finally, Data, + ,- and GRND are connectors. I'm not sure what they look like. Try to find a connector that fits the one originally planned or simply solder wire. It really depend how you want to use this circuit.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, thank you. 

I realize that the connectors are not actually any placed components, so I can remove that. 

For NCP161, the package in the eagle files didn't look right so after looking at the Datasheets and the board, I realize it should be 4-XDFN package. This narrowed it down to two options, one with active discharge and one without. I will go forward with [the one without active discharging](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/NCP161BMX330TBG/5257739?s=N4IgTCBcDaIHIGEAKBGAbCgQgWQBoGZ8AGAFUwHEQBdAXyA) since you mentioned it is not used.

Comment: I am still a little unsure about my choices for [L1 (Ferrite Bead)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/murata-electronics/BLM15AG221SN1D/1948285) and [U$4,U$5 (Diode)](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/SBRT05U20LPS-7B/7666996). Would you mind confirming if these look ok to use?

Comment: For your ferrite, I don't  know what kind of noise they try to suppress with it.  But as mentioned, many designer placed them for no real reason. So, the one you selected (if the footprint matches) should work perfectly fine. It's DC resistance is low enough to not impact the rest of the circuit.

Comment: The diode is highly dependent on your battery. If it's a 12V battery, that's perfect, the forward voltage won't be an issue. On the other hand, if you are using a 18650 or similar lithium cell, the vbat voltage will be 3.7V. Since your LDO is 3.3, the dropout voltage of the LDO0.15, if you add an other 0.4V, the minimum voltage for the battery is 3.85V making it unsuitable.  You know best what is your requirement!. Other then that, I don't see any issue with that diode!